# PHP number_format take first digits only

Tags: php

Is it possible to get only the first 3 digit of a number from `number_format`?

My number is like `550000` which I put into `<?php number_format($package->price,0) ?>`. This returns `550,000`. I'm looking for a solution to get `550` and `000` separately, I'm willing to use 2 `<?php ... ?>` if required.

**Is this possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can use PHP's [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split your number on the comma `,`, like this:

```
echo explode(',', number_format($package->price, 0))[0]; // => 550
echo explode(',', number_format($package->price, 0))[1]; // => 000
```

Comment: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: @mafortis Try splitting on `','` instead, I think you posted `550.000` on accident, and it should have been `550,000` with a comma.

Comment: working now thanks, please wait for 4 min till i can accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to explode by ','

Documentation: [Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

**See This:**

```
print_r(explode(',',number_format(550000,0)));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 550
    [1] => 000
)
```